# Voice Recognition android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

How I make **[speech to text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)** application on *Android* to work continuously 
(i.e; **without** click the button) every time I want to speak ?
Which event may i use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)

Check out the `recognizeDirectly` method within this class:
https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity.java

Caveat: The current Android api doesn't work reliably. It will likely record continuously for a while and then crash. Also, it will beep at your users in the later versions of Android, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private ListView resultList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    // to check if recognizer available or not
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recognizer Not Found",
                1000).show();
    }

    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
}

private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "AndroidBite Voice Recognition...");
    intent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,
            5000000);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        System.out.println("Matches list " + matches);
        resultList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

//It will solve your problem

Comment: It is to be noted that there must be a ListView with the ID "list" in your activity_main layout for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a service, which will run in back ground, you have to study one class **RecognitionService** and one interface **RecognitionListener**
cheers