# taking input from user through voice

Tags: android

hi i developed a application with name  "route tracker for special person"
, it is developed for blind person. in my app,  voice instruction is given to user but user will give input through clicking on some part of screen as instructed by application. 
now i want to take input from user in term of voice.
kindly give description.

```
package com.example.routetracker;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Select_destination extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button close,main,about,texila,aslam_market,royal_son,comsat;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_destination);

    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.selectdestination);


            mPlayer.start();
            texila=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_texila);
            texila.setOnClickListener(this);
            aslam_market=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_aslam_market);
            aslam_market.setOnClickListener(this);
            royal_son=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_royal_son);
            royal_son.setOnClickListener(this);
            comsat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_comsat_wah);
            comsat.setOnClickListener(this);
            main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
            main.setOnClickListener(this);
            about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
            about.setOnClickListener(this);
            close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
            close.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_texila:
        mPlayer.stop();

        Intent i=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        i.putExtra("place", "1");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_aslam_market:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent j=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        j.putExtra("place", "2");
        startActivity(j);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_royal_son:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent k=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        k.putExtra("place", "3");
        startActivity(k);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_comsat_wah:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent l=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        l.putExtra("place", "4");
        startActivity(l);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_main:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent o=new Intent(Select_destination.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(o);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_about:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent e=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Sample.class);
        startActivity(e);
        break;



    case R.id.btn_close:
        mPlayer.stop();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Not to sound mean or something but _what exactly_ are you asking here?
What kind of input do you want to take? Clicks on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use voice recognition in your application..below links may help you.....

[tutorial1](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)

[tutorial2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html)

[tutorial3](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-android-voice-recognition/)

Answer (score 3):

You Definetly need Something like Voice Recognition :

Here i the Helping material for you to go on

[help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057725/voice-recognition-android)